# Displaying different types of objects in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

### What I'm trying to do

I am doing a search across several different models using Sphinx in my rails application, and it successfully returns the weighted results (including several different types of objects, let's say posts and users). I currently am testing this with (`many.each { |one| one.inspect }`), and that works fine.

I am now trying to write a method for each model with the same name that will output my objects in the format that I choose. For example, instead of `one.inspect`, I'd like to put `one.print_pretty` and have it output html that neatly prints out the information specific to that type of object. Using the user example, I'd like it to output something like:

```
<div class="small-2 columns">
    <%= image_tag(one.userpic.avatar.url) %>
</div>
<div class="small-10 columns">
    <div class="row">
        <h3 class="subheader"><%= one.first + " " + one.last %></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <%= one.tagline %>
    </div>
</div>
```

By contrast, on my post model, it should output something different that's applicable to the post attributes and priorities.

### Question

**How do I write a method for a Rails model that will output an html-styled chunk to code or otherwise style output that's of an unknown object type (from a limited pool)?**

Comment: I would code that in a helper instead the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?  You could create a separate partial that would show a different output for each object class.  In your view, pass the object into a helper method function.  For example:

```
<%= render_partial_for_this_type_of_object(your_object) %>
```

Then in a helper method, have something like:

```
def render_partial_for_this_type_of_object(object)
    if object.class.name == "ClassA"
        render 'class_a_partial', :object => object
    elsif object.class.name == "ClassB"
         render 'class_b_partial', :object => object
    end
end
```

So to summarize, you are passing the object from the view to the helper, identifying what class of object it is, then passing that object to the appropriate partial based on its class that will then be rendered in the view.

I'm sure there are other ways to do this but this worked well for me in an app I just built.

Comment: That way could definitely work. I am displaying between 25 and 50 results per page, depending on user settings though; do you know whether there would be performance implications to rendering that many partials in a page?

Comment: I don't believe rendering a partial is any more computationally intensive than rendering the code from a helper method or from the view itself.  And it is a lot cleaner to keep track of.  I'm using it with 10-20 partials being rendered in the same view and have seen no issues.

Comment: Check this out: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/157108/rails-does-using-partials-slow-views-rendering.  It answers your question about performance a little more fully.  Might be some negatives to rendering a lot of partials since it has to call the method to render the partial each time.  But I wouldn't worry about it much and I think it will be negligible.

Comment: I actually figured out why my code wasn't working before: by tacking .html_safe at the end of the string in my helper method, I could return html and have it actually render as such. In case someone stumbles across this, that's another alternative to partials.

Comment: Yes, that would also work and I use that approach when there is a very small amount of html code in my helper methods.  But I think it makes it harder to maintain your code when you have some html code sitting in helper methods and some in your view directories.